# Series expansion in variables with different indices

Tags: series-expansion

The `Series[]` command is useful for reformatting algebraic expressions and getting rid of higher-order terms:

```
In[1]:= Series[ a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + a4*x^4, {x, 0, 2}] 
Out[2]:= a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + O(X^3)
```

Now suppose we have a variable which also has indices (e.g. $x_i$ with $i=1, ..., N$), and we want to find expansion of a term up to some order of the variable which neglects the indices. For instance, given an expression
\begin{equation}
 a_0 + a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + a_{11} x_1^2 + a_{12} x_1 x_2 + a_{22} x_2^2 + a_{111} x^3 + etc.
\end{equation}
I'd like to have an expansion which to lowest orders $k$ gives
\begin{align}
 k=0&: a_0 + O(x_i)\\
 k=1&: a_0 + a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2  + O(x_i^2) \\
 k=2&: a_0 + a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + a_{11} x_1^2 + a_{12} x_1 x_2 + a_{22} x_2^2  + O(x_i^3) \\
\end{align}

Is there any command to do this?

Comment: `f[x_] := a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + a4*x^4;
Table[Series[a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + a4*x^4, {x, 0, k}], {k, 0, 
  5}]`

Comment: Do a search on 'mathematica stackexchange multivariate series' (without quotes) and there will be several relevant hits.

Comment: Yes, it does, thanks!